# Significant T-test with small mean difference but large standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean

I have recently run some analyses to test whether those participants lost to follow up are significantly different from those who stayed in the study. N= 590 for those who stayed and N=258 for those lost.

I ran independent T-tests to compare the two groups on a variety of measures. All were Non-significant except one variable. However I'm not sure what this means practically- the mean difference was 1.41 on a questionnaire which is relatively small but the Standard deviations are fairly large (7.92 and 8.59 for each group respectively). Would appreciate anyone who can help me make sense of this?

Because of the large SD does it make the small mean difference not meaningful?

Comment: The large sample size means that the *standard error* of each of the means is quite small.

Comment: Sorry! The standard errors of the means is .326 and .535. What does that mean for the above t-test?

Comment: @Dan It means that you’ve observed a surprising result, if the null hypothesis is true, the usual interpretation of the p-value. It concerns me, though, that you’re looking at measure after measure until one is significant. There’s a cartoon about this: https://xkcd.com/882/. Anyway, not every statistically significant difference has to have practical significance. It’s okay to use your expertise in the field to say, “Yeah, but that puny difference isn’t interesting.” You’re allowed to do that if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Dave that makes a lot of sense! Haha- good cartoon and I see the point you're raising. Would you suggest any better method to test whether the attrition group is broadly similar to those who remained in my study therefore reducing the effect of any attrition bia?

Comment: You could always run a logistic regression predicting drop-out as a function of the predictors.

Comment: Thanks for the good cartoon.  They checked 20 colors and only one of them has p < .05...

Comment: Not sure if you found your answer... if not, it might be helpful to share example or your data. Also, you could include the mean of each sample since you have mentioned their SD.

Comment: @Dan In addition to the other good suggestions, I might add that effect size (Cohen's d) can be helpful in seeing what is a "meaningful" different - past just being significant. Of course, effect sizes interpretation can be dependent on what field you are researching in.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the mean difference is small (as compared to standard deviations), the difference can still be significant due to large sample sizes, which is what is happening with your data.  Using R:

```r
DescTools::TTestA(1.41, 7.92, 590, 
+        0,    8.59, 258) 
> 

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 2.2511, df = 456.09, p-value = 0.02485
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.179107 2.640893
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     1.41      0.00 

DescTools::TTestA(1.41, 7.92, 590, 
+        0,    8.59, 258, var.equal=TRUE) 
> 

    Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 2.3238, df = 846, p-value = 0.02037
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2190621 2.6009379
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     1.41      0.00
```

although the lower end of the confidence interval is just above 0.